# Configure Import Order in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, import

So it seems like the default import order of Android Studio is purely alphabetical. This leads to imports like

[image]

Tell me this doesn't make you want to cringe.

Of course, import order is not going to affect anything in any way, except for maybe my mood (if this is the first code I see when I begin the day, I know my app is going to crash)

What I'd like to see, in order, is:

- java
- kotlin
- android
- (Third-Party Libraries)

Is there any way to do this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for this?:

**Settings > Editor > Java > Imports (Tab) > (Scroll Down) > Import Layout**

[image: Imports Setting]